# Elasticsearch Query for getting field with 'AND' relation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm having elastic document as below

[image: elasticDoc]

I want a search query satisfying condition:
how to get the those OPERATIONS and CATEGORY  values that has both AREA=Mumbai and AREA=Chennai

> So Output should be CATEGORY:Consulting1 , OPERATIONS: Regulatory Operations

Answer (score 1):

Use `terms Query` :

```
 {
  "query": {
    "terms": {
       "AREA": [
          "Mumbai",
          "Chennai"
       ]
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I already tried it but it is not giving AND relation, it gives OR relation between Mumbai and Chennai

Comment: Do you have multiple values in `AREA` field. Documents specified above don't have any such value???

Comment: Yes, we have multiple values in every column.

Comment: please share that type of document and mapping of your index too.

Comment: Friend I can't, it's confidential but scenario is exactly as mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

May be that works:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"term": { "AREA" : "Mumbai" }},  
                {"term": { "AREA" : "Chennai" }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you specify an example document and the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "AREA": "mumbai"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "AREA": "chennai"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_operations": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "OPERATIONS",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count_areas": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "AREA"
          }
        },
        "top": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 2,
            "_source": {
              "include": ["CATEGORY"]
            }
          }
        },
        "areas_bucket_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "areasCount": "count_areas"
            },
            "script": "areasCount == 2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**LATER EDIT**: added `top_hits` aggregation to get back sample documents covering the request for the categories.

Comment: Didn't worked this also friend giving: "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures {[PnxXsZacRoilcOsys3T3Eg]

Comment: That's not the complete error message. Please, provide the **complete error message**. And, also, that query will work on ES 2.x+. With ES 1.x you can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "AREA",
            "query": "mumbai"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "AREA",
            "query": "chennai"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}[![result][1]][1]
```

Comment: it is not giving AND relation

Comment: I have checked it and it is giving expected result. Could you share your elasticsearch version with us?

Comment: I think should stands for 'OR' so how it can give result with both mumbai and chennai?

Comment: Your thinking is right. It works as 'OR'. It means it will return both type of document which may contain 'chennai' or 'mumbai'. But, if you use 'must' then it will check a document which must contain both the values. That's why everyone is recommending you the approx same query. I have added result snap for you.

Comment: but using must gives no result friend, means 0 encounter

Comment: You are totally confused. I have also mentioned if you have any record which have "chennai" and "mumbai" then must will return any result. It is very strange that you are not sharing your version number.